# Behavior of synchronized method and block is different

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized-block

I observed a scenario where use of synchronized method or synchronized block producing different results.
 From below code:

```
class Callme {
    void call(String msg) {
        System.out.print("[" + msg);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }       
}

class Caller implements Runnable{
    String msg;
    Callme target;
    Thread t;

    public Caller(Callme target, String msg) {
        this.target = target;
        this.msg = msg;
        t = new Thread(this, "Caller thread");
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(target) {
            target.call(msg);
            new Callme().call(msg);
        }
    }

}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Callme obj = new Callme();

        new Caller(obj, "thread1");
        new Caller(obj, "thread2");
        new Caller(obj, "thread3");

        Thread.currentThread().join();
    }
}
```

When I use the synchronized block in the Caller::run method the ouput is synchronized as below:

```
[thread1]
[thread1]
[thread3]
[thread3]
[thread2]
[thread2]
```

But when I use the synchronized method for the Callme::call method, instead of synchronized block, the output is not synchronized:

```
[thread1]
[thread1[thread2]
]
[thread3[thread2]
]
[thread3]
```

My Expectation is the output should not be synchronized on both cases because I am using different objects when calling the "Callme::call" method

This made me question my understanding of the Synchronized block concept?

Answer (score 1):

A synchronized method is equivalent to a `synchronized(this)`-block for the length of the entire method, however your code is using `synchronized(target)`, and `target` is a shared instance of `Callme`. In other words: the object being synchronized on is different, so the behavior is not the same.

In the case you use `synchronized(target)`, it means that all threads synchronize on the same instance of `Callme` so their behavior is serial: a thread will hold the monitor of that `Callme` instance for the whole duration of the `Caller.run` method, so in effect the threads are executed one after the other.

In the case of a synchronized method, the threads each synchronize on their own instance of `Caller`, so in effect there is no serialization (except for the writes to `System.out`).

Some additional remarks:

- Calling `Thread.currentThread().join()` is a bad idea, because it will wait on itself
- In general don't create and start `Thread` instances in the `Runnable` implementation that is going to be run by that thread: you lose access to the thread. Especially don't do this in the constructor, because you are publishing a partially constructed object to the `Thread`, which is not a big problem in this code, but might lead to subtle bugs in more complex applications.